# Angular 10 inside loop breaking

Tags: angular

I am just developing the UI as per this design (https://codepen.io/ThomasDaubenton/pen/QMqaBN). But I don't know how can I break the loop after the first message so that the profile pic div section will not repeat.

```
<div *ngFor="let msg of msgs">
                        <div >
                       <div class="message"  >
                        <div class="photo" style="background-image: url({{LManager_photo}});">
                          <div class="online"></div>
                        </div>
                        <p class="text"> {{msg.Message}} </p>
                      </div>
                      
                      <div class="message text-only">
                        <p class="text"> {{msg.Message}} </p>
                      </div>
                      <p class="time"> 14h58</p>
                          
                    </div> 
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div *ngFor="let msg of msgs; let i = index">
                        <div >
                       <div class="message"  >
                        <div *ngIf="i===0" class="photo" style="background-image: url({{LManager_photo}});">
                          <div class="online"></div>
                        </div>
                        <p class="text"> {{msg.Message}} </p>
                      </div>
                      
                      <div class="message text-only">
                        <p class="text"> {{msg.Message}} </p>
                      </div>
                      <p class="time"> 14h58</p>
                          
                    </div> 
   </div>
```